# Homotopy type of transversal submanifolds through deformation

Tags: homotopy-theory, gradient-flows, transversality

Let $A,B \subset M$ be two transversal submanifolds of a compact manifold $M$. It seems rather intuitive that if $A$ and $B$ are deformed (say smoothly) in a way that they remain transversal to each other, the homotopy type of the intersection remains unchanged during the deformation.

I would like to know if there is a way to write such a homotopy in the following situations:

1. $A = f^{-1}(0)$ is the zero level set of some smooth function $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$, and $B = B_s$ is a smooth family of submanifolds such that $A$ and $B_s$ are always transverse. Is it true that the homotopy type of $A \cap B_s$ is independent of $s$ ?
2. $A_s := f_s^{-1}(0)$ is the zero set of a smooth function $f_s : M \to \mathbb{R}$, and the family $A_s$ is always transversal to a fixed submanifold $B$. Is it true that the homotopy type of $A_s \cap B$ is independent of $s$ ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need an extra hypothesis to rule out dumb counterexamples, such as an open interval and a circle embedded in a 2-manifold.

Comment: What would be the problem with your example ? We can assume that the submanifolds are compact if this helps.

Comment: Ignoring compactness, let $M$ be the coordinate plane, $B$ be the $y$-axis, and $A$ be the interval $(-2,-1)$ along the $x$-axis. Now homotope $A$ by sliding it to the right: $A_t = (-2+t,1+t)$. For $t \le 1$ and $t \ge 2$, $A_t$ is transverse to $B$ because it is disjoint. For $1 < t < 2$, $A_t$ is transverse to $B$ at one point.

Comment: Thank you. Would compactness fix the problem ?

Comment: I think it should.

Comment: Couldn't you apply the same argument with the closed interval $[-2,-1]$ ?

Comment: That would not work if the term "submanifold" were restricted to have empty boundary.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you.